Namespace issue in LWC component in Scratch Org
I have created a namespaced scratch org from a DevHub org. I can see the namespace prefix for fields, objects and apex in the scratch org. We have few LWC component as well in the package where I need to add the namespaces in the code in order to work.
Ex.
    this.sectionRelatedData.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (this.sectionId == element.sectionId) {
            element.sectionName = this.sectionVal;
            let field = {}
            field['Id'] = this.sectionId;
            field['EventTechHub__Section_Name__c'] = element.sectionName;
            const recordInput = {
                fields: field
            }
            updateRecord(recordInput)
                .then(() => {
                    this.showToast('Success!!', 'Updated successfully!!', 'success');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.showToast('Error!!', error.body.message, 'error');
                });
        }
    })

In the above code we have to add the namespace prefix "EventTechHub__" in order for it to work.
Is there any way to get rid of hardcoded namespace for development?

Import your fields, and use the relevant tokens:
import EVENT_SECTION_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Event_Section__c.Event_Section_Name__c";

field[EVENT_SECTION_NAME.fieldApiName] = element.sectionName;

Salesforce will automatically provide the namespace, or not, depending on the context.

There are two ways to fetch the namespace dynamically:

Create a Global variable in any one of the class to store the namespace

Use the wire method to fetch the object info and namespace


    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: 'EventTechHub__Section__c' })
    objectInfo;

    get namespace() {
        return this.objectInfo.data ? this.objectInfo.data.namespace : '';
    }

